# Why can't I insert DBNull.Value into a nullable image-field in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, c#-2.0, nullable, dbnull

Why can't I insert `DBNull.Value` into a nullable `image`-field in sql server 2005?

I tried this code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=PrescriptionTrackingSystem;Integrated Security=True");

            conn.Open();

            SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Customer(
                               ID
                              ,Name
                              ,TelephoneNumber
                              ,DateOfBirth,
                               InsuranceProvider,
                               PolicyNumber,Photo)
                          VALUES(
                               @ID
                              ,@Name
                              ,@TelephoneNumber
                              ,@DateOfBirth,
                               @InsuranceProvider,
                               @PolicyNumber,
                               @Photo)", conn);

            command.Transaction = transaction;

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 1000);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", item.Name);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TelephoneNumber", item.TelephoneNumber);
            if (item.DateOfBirth != null)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", item.DateOfBirth);
            }
            else
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", DBNull.Value);
            }
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InsuranceProvider", item.InsuranceProvider);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PolicyNumber", item.PolicyNumber);

            if (item.Photo != null)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", item.Photo);
            }
            else
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", DBNull.Value);
            }

            int count = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            transaction.Commit();

            conn.Close();
```

item is of type `Customer`.

```
public class Customer
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string InsuranceProvider { get; set; }
    public int? PolicyNumber { get; set; }
    public byte [] Photo { get; set; }
}
```

When inserting I get this exception:

```
Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with image
```

Why `DBNull.Value` has got problems only with `image`? Why not with `datetime`?

Comment: What about the stored proc, what is the data type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Photo", SqlDbType.Image).Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be to do with the fact that you are not explicitly defining the SqlParameter.SqlDbType and think it will be assuming NVARCHAR. Instead of using AddWithValue, trying adding a new SqlParameter and setting SqlDbType explicitly to SqlDbType.Image.

Here's the [MSDN ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.sqldbtype.aspx) which states the default is NVARCHAR.

Comment: Yes. But I have posted my code and you can see DateTime is working correctly.

Comment: A NULL NVARCHAR can be cast to a DATETIME without problem. However, a NULL NVARCHAR cannot be cast to an IMAGE as you get a conversion error. Give it a try, setting the SqlDbType to Image for that parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly specify the parameter's type as SqlDbType.Image

Comment: Yes. But I have posted my code and you can see DateTime is working correctly.

Comment: Yes, thats because there EXISTS implicit conversions between nvarchar to datetime and it treats NULL values as it should. And there is no any implicit conversions from nvarchar to Image, even if value is NULL

Comment: Is the conversion associated with SqlServer2005 or SqlCommand object?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this like this:

```
If (Photo.Equals(DBNull.Value)) Then
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Photo", SqlDbType.Image).Value = DBNull.Value
Else
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Photo", Photo)
End If
```